# Trigger for WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть стиль с дататриггером:

1. Можно ли на дата триггре менять как то value по ходу выполнения программы? Сейчас пишет мол триггер после использования становится sealed. И менять его нельзя. Т.е. сейчас я пересобираю заново весь стиль, а это много кода. Особенно когда в стиле много триггеров и сеттерров.
2. Как быстро скопировать стиль базовый? Сейчас я форычем пробегаюсь по TriggerCollection и по коллекциям сеттеров, опять же это куча кода((  и потом его применяю на нужном мне айтеме.

Comment: Вы делаете что-то не то, подобная эквилибристика обычно не нужна. Расскажите, чего вы хотите этим добиться, какая ваша реальная проблема.

Comment: Есть значение, некая сумма столбца дата грида 1. Сравнивается с эталоном и в зависимости от результата крашу ячейку датагрида 2.Датагрид 2 это одна стррка с итогами. Например сумма в столбце равна 3 - зеленый. Потом добавляются и удаляются строки в датагриде 1, и вот это значение идеальное (3) , может поменятся. И теперь тройка будет не зеленый, а желтый цвет выдавать, а зеленый 3,5 допутим.

Comment: Это похоже на бизнес-логику, я бы не кодировал это вовсе триггерами, а вынес в VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчёт первого вопроса — как вариант, можно использовать в Binding DataTrigger’а некий MultiValueConverter, чтобы тот в качестве значений принимал текущий Binding и Value и сравнивал их.

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualToBooleanConverter}">
            <Binding Path="CurrentValue" />
            <Binding Path="RequiredValue" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
</DataTrigger>
```

Сам MultiValueConverter, например, может выглядеть как-то так:

```
public class EqualToBooleanConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return values.Length > 1 && values.Skip(1).All(x => Equals(values[0], x));
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересное решение, попробую.